# Why not getting .env file values after running the comman 'config:cache && cache:clear' in laravel on cpanel

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 5.6. I have to send email using https://mailtrap.io/ while i tested it with all my credentials of mailtrap.io, it returns me `connection timed out error`. I googled and got a solution i.e running `config:cache && cache:clear` artisan command. I ran it using ssh key on my cpanel. Now i can't get `.env` file's value. Before executing the `config:cache && cache:clear`command, i used to get those value in my controller with `env('APP_ENV')` or `$_ENV(['APP_ENV'])`. Here is my `.env` file:

```
APP_ENV=local
INSTALLED=1
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:NtWQxDuzGxM8vdDCYwq4utnmiNimk4kJI4oyiUEA38w=
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=db_user_name
DB_PASSWORD=user_password
```

Now I don't understand what should i do?

Comment: show also the **mailtrap** configuration code in `.env` file

Comment: now my problem is how to get .env file values, after getting the value i can access mailtrap credentials code

Comment: Well, once I had a similar problem, just to know, are you sending an image in that mail? My problem relied in having a image incorrectly linked to the mail, so that when laraves tried to find it, the connection timed out error appeared,

Comment: no, there was just message successfully tested